# Setting up Python on Vs code Mac

Tags: python-3.x

I've attached the picture of the end product when I run my code does anyone know why this is happening, I've setup Python on Vs Code twice and still have the same issue when I run the code.

/bin/sh: python: command not found this the error message

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr59H.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH3O8.png

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Windows, Mac uses `python3` instead of `python`.

try this on your terminal:

```
$ python3 path/to/file.py
```

If that works, you could add an alias like this:

```
$ echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc
```

This way you can use python in place of python3 like

```
$ python path/to/file.py
```

I hope it helps :D